# How to integrate CKFinder with Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5, ckfinder

Since Laravel 5.2 shares it's session only with routes enclosed in "web" middleware group, I no more can run Auth::check() in CKFinder config. Does someone know how to solve this?

update:
I used to share laravel's 5 session with CKFinder in order to give access permissions for authorized users. Like this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

function CheckAuthentication()
{    
    return Auth::check() && auth()->user()->isAdmin();
}
```

But now since all routes should be wrapped in group with 'web' middleware, routes outside that group just wouldn't let to use Auth::user()

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
});
```

How to put CKFinder routes to 'web' middleware to be able to use Laravel's session?

Comment: Please state the problem as clearly as possible. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, I want to allow use of CKFinder only for admin (authorized) users. I've updated my question. Hope it is now more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy.
just modify the Kernel.php

```
 protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

then try again。

Comment: Thanks, that works! But doesn't it break security of laravel?

Comment: Yes! that fix integrate ckfinder upload fail auth bug

Answer (score 1):

kernel object has a function "pushMiddleware".

use this function to run middleware "EncryptCookies" and "StartSession".

it works for me :)

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
->pushMiddleware(\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class)
->pushMiddleware(\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class)
->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

function CheckAuthentication()
{    
    return Auth::check() && auth()->user()->isAdmin();
}
```

Comment: thank you! I'll try that one. It looks like native approach instead of  removing "web" middleware from all routes group

Comment: Did anybody get this to work when actually uploading files? I ended up getting MethodNotAllowed exceptions

Comment: Hmm... I got an error on Laravel 5.8 CLI "Call to a member function make() on boolean" for $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel') Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the accepted answer here is the way to go about this, and the other answer doesn't work when uploading files (MethodNotAllowed exception).

I got it to work by using regular sessions - so in Laravel, on user login:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ckfinder_auth'] = true;
```

On user log out:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['ckfinder_auth']);
```

Within ckfinder config:

```
session_start();

function CheckAuthentication()
{
    return !empty($_SESSION['ckfinder_auth']);
}
```

A tad messy having to use regular sessions in Laravel, but it works, and it's secure.

Comment: Could you clarify why you believe that the accepted answer is not the correct reason to go about this?

Comment: Well for one I don't believe the solution would even work (I think you'd still end up getting MethodNotAllowed exceptions when uploading), but secondly, it's moving the session middleware to start on all http requests, which is creating unnecessary additional load on many requests (e.g. api requests).